# How to you interact with your website via Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I want to interact with a website via Chromes Developer Console.

How can I fire for example a click-event on a button `<button class="usethis">My Button</button>`?

Thanks

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: I don't want to select tags by class name, I want to interact with them on the website, so if a link to another page has class "linktopage" I would like to use some command to use the class and visit the page after entering the command

Comment: You mean like 'click-button-x'?

Comment: Yes I'd like to click a button or link and have it do something when I execute the command.

Comment: Doing some automation testing and the tags I have ain't working, thus I'd like to use Dev tools in Chrome to test whether the tags work or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy/Paste this into the Chrome Dev Tools, console window on a page which contains the class usethis on a button, this will select anything with that class and click it.

```
$("#body .usethis").trigger("click");
```